# How to iterate through json file in Java

Tags: java, json

In my Json file I have the following field:

```
"categories": [{
  "name1": "Corporate",
  "parent": {
      "name_parent": "PlanType1"
}
}],
```

In my Java file I have this code to access that json variable:

`PlanType.getnewEntity().getCategories().`

The `.getCategories()` is accessing the `"categories"` json variable, I just am having trouble iterating through `"categories"`

In my code I need the logic that if in `"categories"` if `name_parent = "PlanType1"` AND `name1 = "Corporate"` do x. I am just having trouble constructing that if statement by iterating through the json.

Comment: Please include the Java code.

Comment: @vsfDawg I have it included

Comment: @vsfDawg do you see it?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate like below

```
 categories.getCategories().forEach(
                category -> {
                    if("Corporate".equals(category.getName1()) &&
                            ("PlanType1".equals(category.getParent().getNameParent()))) {

                        //do the logic
                    }
                }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I don't actually know how the JSON variable you are getting. But it would work if u cast it into a List of Maps. For example

```
List<Map<String, Object>> catogoriesList = (List<Map<String, Object>>) PlanType.getnewEntity().getCategories();
```

Then you'll be able to iterate through it like as follows.

```
for(Map<String, Object> catogory : catogoriesList){
  Map<String, Object> parent = (Map<String, Object>) catogory.get("parent");
  if(catogory.get("name1").toString().equals("Corporate") && parent.get("name_parent").toString().equals("PlanType1")){
    // Do x here
  } 
}
```